# innertext return all the child and self text. how do i except one child text

Tags: c#

I have an xml file

```
<first>
   first1
   <second>second1</second>
   first2
   <third>third1</third>
   first3
</first>
```

I want to read self text for `<first>` and child text for `<third>` except the child `<second>`

answer should be

```
first1 first2 third1 first3
```

I tried:

```
.select(descendant::first1[not(descendant::second)]
```

but it's not working. Need sug

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 1):

```
  XElement elem = XElement.Parse(xml);      
  var query = (from e1 in elem.Nodes()
                    where e1.GetType() == typeof(XText)
                    select (e1 as XText).Value.Trim())
                    .Union(from e2 in elem.Descendants()
                               where e2.Name.LocalName.Equals("third")
                               select e2.Value);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to get the the XML in XMLDocument and play with it.

```
 XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
  doc.LoadXml(xml);
  var nodes = doc.DocumentElement.ChildNodes;
  StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
  {
    if (!node.Name.Equals("second"))
    {
      result.Append(node.InnerText);
      result.Append(" ");
    }
  }
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: `DataSet.ReadXml` is only useful for loading XML formatted for the DataSet. If you have XML that does not conform to this (such as the example in the post) - then this won't work, and you'll get an exception on ReadXml.

Comment: I stand corrected - it doesn't throw exceptions, however the result is... probably not terribly useful. How do you extract the first1, first2, first3 values? They don't appear to be present on the table, or on the dataset.

Comment: Agreed, can not read first1, first2, first3. Thanx for your quick comment on the same. My concern here was people use to explain the things without executing the pasted code :)